# assembly x8086 undefined reference to 'pause'

Tags: assembly, x86-16, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to assemble a simple file and then i want to stop the video to see what I've done. The code is:

```
*.GLOBAL _main
.DATA
stringa:    .ASCIZ "Questa e' la stringaaa"
lettera:    .BYTE 'e'
conteggio:  .BYTE 0x00
.TEXT
_main:      NOP
            MOV $0x00, %CL
            LEA stringa, %ESI
            MOV lettera, %AL
comp:       CMPB $0x00, (%ESI)
            JE fine
            CMP (%ESI), %AL
            JNE poi
            INC %CL
poi:        INC %ESI        
            JMP comp
fine:       MOV %CL, conteggio
            CALL pause
            RET*
```

when I try to assemble in the cmd using the command:
    *gcc -o file file.s*
I get the state:

```
C:\Users\User name\AppData\Local\Temp\ccegNf7o.o:fake:(.text+0x23): 
undefined reference to `pause'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems simple but I tried so hard and still don't succeed.

Comment: `pause` is not a function you can't `call` it. Try `call getchar` instead.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `ret` in a debugger, or run your program from inside an already-existing terminal window, if you can't configure a terminal to stay open after running your program.

Comment: I tried and it's the same, instead of 'pause' there's 'getchar'

Comment: Actually use `_getchar` as your environment apparently uses leading underscore on functions. (Also let me correct myself: `pause` is a function at least per POSIX, but it's probably not what you were looking for.)

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!